# How to pass argument while triggering monaco editor action `editor.action.selectToBracket`

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I am trying to add the functionality to select everything inside the braces when user double click inside it.

My code looks something like this:

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const myEditor = monaco.editor.create(container, {
    value,
    language: "json",
    automaticLayout: true,
});

container.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    const actionId = 'editor.action.selectToBracket',
        args = { selectBrackets: false}
    myEditor.trigger(null, actionId, JSON.stringify(args));
});
```

Monaco playground link: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.39.0#XQAAAAIyAgAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw0pzbeVciAKctgAboa7BDe5w81D0NzWWcrRMcpvivy8dxflGgeKGGN0QXI3M-x42qF2vF5Z-o_2911jbrUcIPciP6j2NpZmpiPjzgiMIFP4hdTsEHWIO2wJhOSbzII2EM7pJch-d7JY_oYAi-iYRaxb0K6fKs4qqUqLZxqKE3G3-ijXOdhfYB3gfkJJT2ADIjrf3vdTq7mXpcj3DHznsuJU-5trMwvGBS6PmnnV5m44Qa9APOlpLLv-Z0ukCxOeI10S8nYJbx561N8mvHIaikowN5p6943RZ-Tof8Fu_VqAb1RzcfmY22b9XwYfgtRVKOtg-GOAFx913j1scIWnrO6NQbB_eeeTv0pl2BzFVDtDg-DwQh5sDD9wcaaX12eLrqlbMsmQm9IETwGkjW0YkA95Es0b69f1LRl68ZPG6iubDqpXvZQ08N_-qTVEE

This has been referenced from here:

- https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/d514ddaa8d0ac3a3c11bffe6d3ca1bf9ee822228/test/smoke/smoke.test.js#L101-L105
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43371

Can someone help me to understand what am I doing wrong here. Since passing this argument to keybinding.json file of VS code is working as expected.